# Why are the coefficients of the second fundamental form of a surface immersed in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by second partial derivatives?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

In my Riemannian geometry course there is a great emphasis on being able to compute the coefficients of the second fundamental form of some surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by an immersion. Let me give a concrete example.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\times (0, 2\pi)\to \mathbb{R}^4$, $f(u, v)=(u\cos v, u\sin v, u^3\cos v, u^3\sin v)$. Then $N=f(\mathbb{R}\times (0, 2\pi))$, i.e. the image of $f$, is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (a submanifold with dimension $2$). The coefficients of the metric on $N$ are given by $$g_{11}=\left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right\rangle,\quad g_{12}=g_{21}=\left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right\rangle, \quad g_{22}=\left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right\rangle,$$ that is we work with the metric induced by $\mathbb{R}^4$ on this submanifold.

When we compute the coefficients of the second fundamental form, we have to compute, for instance, $$\left\langle h(e_1, e_2), e_3\right\rangle,$$ where $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is an orthonormal basis in $T_p M$ and $\{e_3, e_4\}$ is an orthonormal basis in $T^{\perp}_p M$.

Finding these bases is straightforward in this case, we just take $e_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{11}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ and $e_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{22}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ and then apply the Gram-Schmidt procedure.

What I don't understand is why in this context $$\left\langle h(e_1, e_2), e_3\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}}}\left \langle\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}, e_3\right\rangle.$$
This boils down to $$h\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v},$$ which is essentially what causes me trouble.

In my course we defined the second fundamental form in general for a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold. I am not sure if there are multiple ways to do it, but just to be precise we seem to have done it in the way Do Carmo does in Chapter 6 of his Riemannian geometry book. I don't understand how to get from that abstract definition to the result I need in this concrete example.

EDIT: I will write down $e_3$ and $e_4$ by the method I was taught. We denote by $J_0:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^4$, $J_0(x, y, z, w)=(-z, -w, x, y)$ the standard complex  structure on $\mathbb{R}^4$. It is straightforward to see that $$\left\langle J_0 e_1, e_2\right\rangle=0$$ and this tells us that $N$ is a Lagrangian surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$, so we may take $e_3=J_0e_1$ and $e_4=J_0e_2$ (this is what I referred to as Gram-Schmidt above; I am not entirely sure how this relates to the classical Gram-Schmidt procedure, but this is what we were told to do without too many explanations).

To make my post easier to follow, I now include the explicit formulas I got for the coeffcients of the metric and for the orthonormal frame:
$$g_{11}=1+9u^4, \quad g_{12}=g_{21}=0, \quad g_{22}=u^2(1+u^4)$$
$$e_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+9u^4}}(\cos v, \sin v, 3u^2\cos v, 3u^2 \sin v)$$
$$e_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^4}}(-\sin v, \cos v, -u^2 \sin v, u^2\cos v)$$
$$e_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+9u^4}}(-3u^2\cos v, -3u^2\sin v, \cos v, \sin v)$$
$$e_4=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^4}}(u^2\sin v, -u^2\cos v, -\sin v, \cos v).$$

Comment: It is far from boiling down to that. Write down actual $e_3$ and $e_4$. I hope you have done concrete computations for surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ (e.g., baby DoCarmo).

Comment: What you've written is a bit confusing, and I'm not even sure what your question is. Could you write down the formulas you got for the components of the metric and also for the orthonormal frame?

Comment: @Deane yes, I am doing this right now as per the above request.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have done concrete computations for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, yes. I edited my post and now I included the formulas for $e_3$ and $e_4$.

Comment: @Deane I included the explicit formulas now. My question is basically why it is true that $\left\langle h(e_1, e_2), e_3\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}}}\left \langle\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}, e_3\right\rangle
$. My instructor always uses equalities of this type to compute the coefficients of the second fundamental form in the context I described in my post. I only wrote down one of the coefficients of the second fundamental form because the others are computed exactly the same changing the corresponding indices.

Comment: The second fundamental form does not have  to be the full Hessian. I do no know what definition of the second fundamental form is, but presumably, you know that $h(v_1,v_2)$ is normal to the surface. The Hessian of $f$ is a vector-valued symmetric matrix. It can be written as a sum of two terms,  a tangential component and a normal component. The second fundamental form is the normal component.

Comment: @Deane yes, I know that $h(v_1, v_2)$ is normal to the surface and that the second fundamental form is the normal component. This is why I am confused why my instructor always uses that formula which indeed seems to imply that the second fundamental form is the full Hessian. Could you tell me a reference where the computation of the second fundamental form of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is done in a proper way?

Comment: I think you're saying that the equation right after "This boils down to" is implies by the equation just before "This boils down to". That's not the case.

Comment: @Deane but are both of these equations true? I thought that $h\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v},
$ implies $\left\langle h(e_1, e_2), e_3\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}}}\left \langle\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}, e_3\right\rangle$ due to the fact that $e_{11}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{11}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$, $e_{22}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{22}}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ and $h$ is bilinear.

Comment: Yes, that implication is true, but the converse is not.

Comment: @Deane yes, I agree with that. But why do we actually have $h\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}$? This is something that I do not understand.

Comment: We don't have that. It's not true in general.

Comment: @Deane oh, I see. So this one isn't true in general. But is $\left\langle h(e_1, e_2), e_3\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}}}\left \langle\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}, e_3\right\rangle$ true in general? In fact this is the one that I am interested in, now I realize that your point was the fact that I was wrong that my question boils down to that wrong equality. I had better not included what I thought my question boiled down to, this seems to have caused confusion about what I was asking.

Comment: Or better said, choosing the orthonormal frame as in my post, does that relation hold?

Comment: Yes, that equation is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$Let $O \subset \R^2$ be open and let $f: O \rightarrow \R^4$ be an embedding. The first fundamental form is
$$ g = g_{ij}\,dx^i\,dx^j, $$
where
$$
g_{ij} = \partial_if\cdot\partial_jf.
$$
For each $x \in O$, there is an orthogonal decomposition
$$
\R^4 = T_x \oplus N_x,
$$
where $T_x$ is the subspace spanned by $\partial_1f(x), \partial_2f(x)$ and $N_x$ is the $2$-plane orthogonal to $T_x$. Let
$$
\pi_x^\perp: \R^4 \rightarrow N_x
$$
denote orthogonal projection onto $N_x$.

The second fundamental form can now be defined as follows (or inferred from a different but equivalent definition): Given any tangent vectors
$$ v= v^1\partial_1f + v^2\partial_2f, w = w^1\partial_1f + w^2\partial_2f, $$
the second fundamental form is defined to bve
$$
h(v,w) = \pi_x^\perp(v^iw^j\partial^2_{ij}f) = v^iw^j\pi_x^\perp(\partial^2_{ij}f) \in N_x.
$$
In other words,
$$
h = h_{ij}\,dx^i\,dx^j,
$$
where
$$
h_{ij} = \pi^\perp_x(\partial^2_{ij}f) \in N_x.
$$
Strictly speaking, $h \in S^2T^*_x\otimes N_x$.

In particular, if $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ is an adapted orthonormal frame, then for any $1 \le i,j \le 2$,
\begin{align*}
e_1\cdot h_{ij} &= 0\\
e_2\cdot h_{ij} &= 0\\
e_3\cdot h_{ij} &= e_3\cdot\partial^2_{ij}f\\
e_4\cdot h_{ij} &= e_4\cdot\partial^2_{ij}f\\
\end{align*}

By the way, the tangential component of $\partial^2_{ij}f$ is essentially the Christoffel symbols of $g$ with respect to the coordinates $(x^1,x^2) \in O$.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help, now I finally understand this. In class that formula just randomly appeared at some point and no one could really figure out an explanation for it. I am glad now I really get it!